# How to remove an unused Specflow feature.xlsx file

Tags: specflow

I am using Specflow+ Excel to include an example data table in my Specflow feature.

To do this I created an Excel file in my project called e.g. Data.feature.xlsx as I thought it needed to be called that initially. Then I realised (as I am only using it for an example table) that it doesn't need to have the feature extension, so I renamed it to e.g. Data.xlsx.

Now, whatever I do I get a build error:

```
 Generation error: Could not find file 'Data.feature.xlsx'
```

I tried cleaning, rebuilding, closing and re-opening the solution. I tried removing the generated .cs and feature files from the relevant folder but the error still persists.

After removing all 3 files from the solution folder (.feature.xlsx, .feature and .feature.cs) I temporarily was able to build, but the next time I edited the Data.xlsx to add more rows to the table the original build error came back.

The error mentions that it is in the file Data.feature.xlsx, which is the one I have removed and I can't find any references to it by searching in the solution.

Is there somewhere this has been recorded that I can't find?

Answer (score 0):

I eventually fixed this the next day after having to completely close all instances of Visual Studio and re-open them so that probably fixed whatever was holding onto it.

Comment: That could be the issue. MSBuild caches some stuff. If you do something with the Excel files in VS, restart VS after it.